# Syntax Error in IE 10 for AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-10

Hi I am building an Angular JS web application. In chrome and FF, it is running fine, but in IE it's acting weird.

I am getting below error :

`SyntaxError<div class="ng-scope" id="mainContainer" data-ng-animate="1" ng-view="">`

in console.
IE version is 10.

Comment: what is the version of AngularJS you're using?

Comment: In html, the div is like this `<div ng-view id="mainContainer"></div>`